# Очень долго отправляется форма, mail() php

Tags: php, битрикс, email

CMS Bitrix, столкнулся с такой проблемой, что формы, которые созданы средствами cms очень долго отправляются, по этому я наверстал свою маленькую форму:

```
<form method="POST" action="/mail.php" class="form_call_back">

        <div>
            <p>Имя</p>
            <input type="text" name="name_call_back">
        </div>

        <br>
        <div>
            <p>Телефон</p>
            <input type="text" name="tel_call_back">
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="button_call_back" class="button_call_back">
        </div>

        <p></p>
    </form>
```

и она(форма) отправляет данные на этот php скрипт:

```
if(isset($_POST['button_call_back']))
{
    $to      = 'mail@mail.ru'; 
    $subject = 'Zvonok';
    $message = 'Имя:'.$_POST['name_call_back'].'<br>Телефон:'.$_POST['tel_call_back'].' <br/>';
    //$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
    $headers = 'From: robot@mail.com';

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    header('Location: /');
}
```

Но когда нажимаю "отправить", страница начинает грузится примерно 1 мин, и только тогда выполняется header('Location: /');

Писал на хостинг, говорят что у них все норм, и функция mail() проверили

Comment: Можно попробовать header('Location: /'); вынести из if и поставить в самое начало. Else у Вас всё равно нет, так что никакой разницы, отправилось письмо или нет

Comment: @humster_spb а тогда все что ниже header('Location: /'); выполнится?

Comment: Должно. Потестируйте. Можете воспользоваться конструкцией header( 'Refresh: 3; url=http://yoursite.ru/' ); - редирект произойдёт через 3 секунды

Comment: Логи sendmail пусть вам скинут если все норм, и что в файле /etc/hosts?
Вот ссылка, похоже у вас то же самое https://askubuntu.com/questions/326879/sendmail-very-slow-etc-hosts-configuration